# DataContractJsonSerializer: Deserialize to different type based on JSON property

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm using DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize JSON from a Webservice.

```
[{"id":2947,"type":"PdfDocument","name":"test.pdf"},
 {"id":2945,"type":"ImageDocument","name":"test.jpg", "color": "green"}]
```

Based on their type, JSON entities can have different properties (for example a color). Currently i use a single model `Document` for deserialization and PagedCollectionViews to filter what i need to show in the UI.

```
public class Document : EntityBase
{
    private string name;
    private string type;
    private string color;

    public Document()
    {
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.name != value)
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.type;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.type != value)
            {
                this.type = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Type");
            }
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "color")]
    public string Color
    {
        get
        {
            return this.color;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.color != value)
            {
                this.color= value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Color");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DocumentsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public ObservableCollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public PagedCollectionView ImageDocuments;

    public PrintProjectDetailsViewModel()
    {            
        this.Documents = new ObservableCollection<Document>();
        this.ImageDocuments = new PagedCollectionView(Documents);
        this.ImageDocuments.Filter = (o) => ((Document)o).Type == "ImageDocument";    
    }
}
```

However, that feels "smelly" to me. Is it possible to automatically deserialize to a subclass of `Document` depending of the JSON value of `type`?

Comment: I don't think there is a way - the `type` field of the .NET object is just a regular string field to the framework. You can try to write functions to hide this, but in the end, it will always be a `switch` that does the distinction.

Comment: First, you'd better switch to Json.NET, it's the preferred Json serializer, used by ASP.NET Web API and the next MVC. DataContractSerializer is ancient, created *before* the form of Json was standardized and has various issues (eg date formatting). Second, deserializing based on a field of a child property is *not* clean either. You can use JSon.Net to deserialize to a dynamic object and then map to whatever you want using the field's value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i would accept that as an answer.